# APA Style: Journal Vol(Num) sometimes, but only Vol other times

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36369/biblatex-apa-output-reference-list-differs-from-that-of-publication-manual-of-th), I noticed the difference between APA Style Guide 6th ed and `biblatex-apa` output. Specifically,

> APA 6th ed (which foregoes the Number of the journal and lists instead
>   only the Volume (perhaps because the page numbers uniformly increase
>   throughout the volume regardless of number, and so perhaps number is
>   redundant?

A few minutes ago, I just noticed that the APA elaborates on this in [an October blog post](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/10/how-to-determine-whether-a-periodical-is-paginated-by-issue.html).

Although it's obvious from the comments in the blog post that this rule is overwhelmingly unpopular (and in my opinion too, it is an idiotic rule), it seems unlikely that the APA will be revising this rule any time soon (especially with their having reimplemented the two-space rule for sentence-ending punctuation with their 6th edition after having previously removed it in older editions after originally requiring it in even older editions).

So I'm guessing that there's no way to automate this, right? It seems like it would require `biblatex` having knowledge of every published journal's pagination scheme (either by issue number or uniformly increasing throughout a volume; perhaps there are other schemes too) which strikes me as a Sisyphean task.

I wonder about automating this not because I'm lazy (although I am lazy in a sense, for I'm always looking for the easiest way to do something), but instead because I'd like to keep a `.bib` database with as much information in it as I know (for my own uses) for each of the references I have in it (even such trivial details as translator and stuff that most style guides don't require or even desire). But now that I see exactly what the APA rule is on this matter (in particular that in some cases (pagination by issue or number), it wants Vol(Num) whereas in other cases (pagination by volume), it wants only Vol and no (Num)), I wonder if there is any way to do this in an APA-compliant manner with `biblatex` other than leaving the `Number` field in the `.bib` entry blank for those journals (which I determine manually) to be paginated by volume.

Sorry for the long-winded background, but in summary, I guess my question is: "Using `LaTeX` and associated tools, what's the best way to handle this arcane and unnecessary rule that was published by the APA just 2 years ago in 2009?"

Comment: Without some kind of meta-data in the bibliography as to the numbering system of any particular volume, I don't think this is possible.  *With* such data (e.g. a custom field, or an external config file with a list of journals that have one numbering or another) it would be possible to do. Leaving the information out of the bib file is not a good solution, since that will remove it for any other style one might use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this will only be possible if you add meta-data to the `.bib` file to indicate whether a particular journal has "per issue" or "per volume" page numbering.  However, this isn't very difficult to do, and you can probably add fields conditionally with your bibliography manager.  Here's an example of how this would work in practice.

I've added a field to each article entry in the bib file called "Type".  This is available automatically to `biblatex`, and can be used for various things.  For clarity I've given the field the values "PerIssue" or "PerVolume"; in practice, you really only need to supply the field for the PerIssue journals (since I suspect they are the minority).

If a journal is numbered per issue (and therefore will require the number in parentheses) we set the Type field to "PerIssue".

Then we declare the field format for `number` to check if the type is "PerIssue" or not. If it is, then the number is formatted; if not it is omitted.

Depending on your reference manager you may be able add the Type field with the correct annotation to every entry with a particular journal name.

```
\documentclass[endnotes]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\def\PerIssue{PerIssue}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\iffieldequals{type}{\PerIssue}{(#1)}{}}
\title{A title}
\author{An Author}
\shorttitle{A title}
\authornote{}
\abstract{An abstract}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Kallio1988,
    Author = {Kallio, Kenneth D.},
    Journal = {Child Development},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {397--410},
    Title = {Developmental Differences in the Comprehension of Simple and Compound Comparative Relations},
    Type = {PerIssue},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/1130319},
    Volume = {59},
    Year = {1988}}

@article{Kavanaugh1976,
    Author = {Kavanaugh, Robert D.},
    Journal = {Child Development},
    Month = {Sep},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {885-887},
    Title = {On the Synonymity of `more' and `less': Comments on a Methodology},
    Type = {PerVolume},
    Volume = {47},
    Year = {1976}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is some text. \cite{kallio1988,kavanaugh1976}
\urlstyle{rm}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Implementation with your reference manager**

In order to implement this scheme you need to tell your reference manager about the extra `Type` field that you are adding to `@article` bib entries.  Both of the popular reference managers (BibDesk on the Mac, and JabRef on any OS) can add custom fields.

*BiBDesk*

- Go to Preferences -> Fields
- Under the Advanced part of the window, choose Custom BibTeX Types and Fields (Edit)
- You will see the following input window, which allows you to add Type as an Optional field to all Article entries.  You need to click on the "Allow editing default types and fields" to do this.

[image: BiBDesk change fields window]

*JabRef*

- Go to Options -> Customize entry types
- You will see the following input window, which allows you to add Type as an Optional field to all Article entries.

[image: JabRef change fields]

Comment: This is a decent solution - it can't really be automated in the style at the moment because one can't guarantee that the "type" field isn't in use etc. Until `biblatex` allows a customisable data model (scheduled for 3.x I think), this can't be solved in a general way in the style.

Comment: Very nice! But a couple of questions to clarify? (1) By 'bibliography/reference manager' I think you mean tools like BibDesk and JabRef. Is that correct? If so, which reference manager are you (and others) using that works with `biblatex`? I'm using JabRef now and it doesn't show me a "Type" field. It also doesn't recognize "journal" as an alias for "journaltitle" although it claims to work with `biblatex` and has a BibLaTeX mode in the preferences. Some customization allowed, but adding 'journal' gets me two diff. fields, 'journaltitle' and 'journal' (I filed a bug report at sf about this).

Comment: I use BibDesk, but both popular reference managers can add custom fields.  I've updated the answer to show how.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Think I failed to communicate my question though. I did add custom fields to JabRef (type & journal). But when I added the custom field, 'journal' (as you had in your example key "Kallio1988"), in JabRef, it didn't handle it as I guessed that a `biblatex`-aware application should: as an alias to journaltitle. It's a different field. Also, new fields have broken JabRef's default layout of fields in its "Optional fields" panel so that it shows *no* fields (all moved to OF2 panel). Just wondering if there was perhaps a more `biblatex`-friendly reference manager out there.

Comment: Also, are you using this with BibDesk?: http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/TypeInfo_biblatex.plist (mentioned at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bibdesk/index.php?title=Tips_and_Tricks ) or are you using BibDesk's original TypeInfo.plist file? Thanks again.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in JabRef. "Journal" is a required and completely standard BibTeX field for the `@article` entry. It has nothing to do with `biblatex`.  When I add the custom field to the Optional Fields as I describe, all of the optional fields are displayed correctly.  Maybe you have an olde version of JabRef?

Comment: In `biblatex`, the "journal" field is not really a field, but instead, an alias to the "journaltitle" field provided for BibTeX compatibility (see **biblatex.pdf** page 28). No, I'm using JabRef 2.7.2. Which version are you running? Maybe try adding two custom fields? I'm having trouble getting back to original panel layout even after removing the two custom fields.

Comment: @TeXnewbie It seems that I have an old version of JabRef (2.6). I use BibDesk since I'm on a Mac; but I'm using the regular `.plist` file, not the `biblatex` specific one. As for the "journal" field, you're right, but my bib file is old, so I'd never noticed that, and neither BibDesk nor my (old) version of JabRef seems to care about it.  But `biblatex` deals with the aliasing I guess, not the reference manager itself.  Maybe you should ask a separate question about the JabRef issue, since I'm certainly not the best person to solve that, but there are lots of users of it here who could help.