# apacite: how to suppress url if doi is avalable?

Tags: apa-style, apa6

I am using apacite package for my BibTex file, but according to my writing style, it's not required for `url` to be listed in the bibliography if `doi` is available. Is there any way I can forced apacite to suppress `url` in bibliography and display only the `doi`?

Comment: Some related questions: [Redundancy in bib file: conditionally suppress url if same as doi?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5660) and [How to sometimes suppress the printing of the URL field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36854).

Answer (score 5):

We can use the specific format of `\bibitem` produced by the `apacite.bst` style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{aa,
  title = "DOI and URL",
  author = "Author, Author",
  year = 2000,
  journal = "Apacite Examples",
  url = "http://www.example.com/1",
  doi = "123/123"
  }
@article{bb,
  title = "Only URL",
  author = "Author, Author",
  year = 2001,
  journal = "Apacite Examples",
  url = "http://www.example.com/2"
  }
@article{cc,
  title = "No DOI no URL",
  author = "Author, Author",
  year = 2002,
  journal = "Apacite Examples" 
  }
@article{dd,
  title = "Only DOI",
  author = "Author. Author",
  year = 2004,
  journal = "Apacite Examples",
  doi = "123/124"
  }
\end{filecontents}


\newtoggle{bibdoi}
\newtoggle{biburl}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\bib@url}
\newsavebox{\bib@doi}

\undef{\APACrefURL}
\undef{\endAPACrefURL}
\undef{\APACrefDOI}
\undef{\endAPACrefDOI}

\newenvironment{APACrefURL}
  {\global\toggletrue{biburl}\lrbox\bib@url}
  {\endlrbox}

\newenvironment{APACrefDOI}
  {\global\toggletrue{bibdoi}\lrbox\bib@doi}
  {\endlrbox}


\newcommand{\printinfo}{
  \iftoggle{bibdoi}{\usebox{\bib@doi}}{\usebox{\bib@url}}
  \togglefalse{bibdoi}
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{
\pretocmd{\PrintBackRefs}{%
  \iftoggle{bibdoi}
    {\iftoggle{biburl}{\unskip\unskip}{}Doi: \usebox{\bib@doi}}
    {\iftoggle{biburl}{Retrieved from \usebox{\bib@url}}}{}
  \togglefalse{bibdoi}\togglefalse{biburl}%
}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{aa}
\cite{bb}
\cite{cc}
\cite{dd}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

`apacite` uses `APACrefURL` and `APACrefDOI` environments to wrap `\url` and `doi`. Thus we can use `lrbox` to store such pieces of text and set toggle to identify whether they are present or not.  Then, `apacite` inserts `\PrintBackRefs` at the end of each `bibitem` thus we can use it to hook into it the commands to print the `url` and `doi`. In this hook we do the reasoning to determine  which ones has to be printed (and undo spaces).

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly. However, with this solution URLs are no longer broken up into multiple lines when they are too long. Is there any way to restore the line breaking?

Comment: There's a new posting -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195512/5001 -- that would like to make use of your method while allowing line breaks to be inserted in url and doi strings. Pleas consider posting an addendum to your answer to show how this might be done. (It would involve *not* using `\lrbox`, right?)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195512/linebreak-in-url for a modification  to the solution that allows line breaks in `url` and `doi` fields.