# Apacite: Supress URL % DOI except for Web Pages

Tags: bibtex, urls

I am using apacite with natbib and have all my literature in Mendeley.

I just found how to supress the URL in the bibliography when DOI is present ([Linebreak in url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195512/linebreak-in-url)). However, I`d like to supress both URL and DOI for all entries, except for web pages - there the URL and the last revised fields should be shown. I am not sure how to change the code from the example above (Linkebreak in url) or how to do that at all - any ideas?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\newtoggle{bibdoi}
\newtoggle{biburl}
\makeatletter
\undef{\APACrefURL}
\undef{\endAPACrefURL}
\undef{\APACrefDOI}
\undef{\endAPACrefDOI}
\long\def\collect@url#1{\global\def\bib@url{#1}}
\long\def\collect@doi#1{\global\def\bib@doi{#1}}

\newenvironment{APACrefURL}{\global\toggletrue{biburl}\Collect@Body  \collect@url}{\unskip\unskip}

\newenvironment{APACrefDOI}{\global\toggletrue{bibdoi}\Collect@Body\collect@doi}{}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{

 \pretocmd{\PrintBackRefs}{%

  \iftoggle{bibdoi}

    {\iftoggle{biburl}{\unskip\unskip}{}}

    {\iftoggle{biburl}{\unskip\unskip }{}}

  \togglefalse{bibdoi}\togglefalse{biburl}%

  }{}{}

}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{PwC2013,
        author = {PwC},
        mendeley-groups = {Sharing},
        title = {{The sharing economy - sizing the revenue opportunity}},
        url = {http://www.pwc.co.uk/issues/megatrends/collisions/sharingeconomy/the-sharing-economy-sizing-the-revenue-opportunity.html},
        urldate = {2015-10-29},
        year = {2013}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\citet{PwC2013}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Wit this code I can get rid of all URLs and DOIs, however, I need them for the web page entries (here misc).

Comment: [Welcome to tex.stackexchange!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551). Could you please provide us a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551) (MWE), that we could compile and work on?

Comment: If I copy and paste your code in a `tex` file and tries to compile it, I get multiple errors: what is the class, where begins the document? Also, learn to format your code by prefixing it with 4 spaces, so that it is displayed as code block.

Comment: Do you use the `misc` field only for webpages? Is switching to [biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/34551) an option?

Comment: @Clément, I use Mendeley`s web page field, however, in bibtex it seems to be "transformed" to misc. Biblatex seems to be more complicated, so I`d be glad to stick to bibtex.

Comment: anyone ideas? I still encounter the problem and cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Off-topic: the title should not be in doubled curly brackets. You are adding a lot of spurious-looking spaces to things. You don't have `\makeatother`. LaTeX will do this anyway, I think, but it seems inelegant.

Comment: Whould it be ok to generate two bibliographies (one for "regular references", and a second one for `@www` and `@misc`)? I've seen this in many publications, and this would make the problem much more easier to solve!

Comment: yes, this would be ok according to the reference guidelines. Do you have a hint of how to separate the bibliographies? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry my bounty was of no use. As a work-around, I propose to either manually edit Mendeley's file, or to switch to Biblatex (which is not complicated at all, and comes with many benefits).