# 'Link'-button instead of complete URL in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, urls

I was wondering whether there is a way to have a 'Link'-button in a bibtex-bibliography which links to the underlying URL, instead of having to show the whole URL for every entry? I find it helpful to be able to directly link to the source online, but the URLs take up a lot of space in my bibliography.

Edit: Add Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} 
\makeatletter 
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands. 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\makeatother 
\usepackage{babel} 

\begin{document} 
    \newpage{}
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

\bibliography{MA_bib,electronic_references}

```
\end{document}
```

Edit: Add bib-entry. This is what my reference manager generates:

```
@article{Giuliano:2009ib,
  author = {Giuliano, Paola and Ruiz-Arranz, Marta},
  title = {{Remittances, financial development, and growth}},
  journal = {Journal of Development Economics},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {90},
  number = {1},
  pages = {144--152},
  month = sep,
  publisher = {Elsevier B.V.},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005},
  uri = {\url{papers3://publication/doi/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005}}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I updated your question with your code. You example should be extended by an example of your bib-file. How do you set an url?

Comment: I find that including DOIs achieves this -- there's enough information on a hardcopy to find the reference, but they're compact. [This question and the links underneath it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136903/apacite-how-to-suppress-url-if-doi-is-avalable) might be of interest.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 8):

If you use `biblatex` you can change the output of `url` by `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

In the example below a symbol of the package `fontawesome` is linked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\href{#1}{\faExternalLink}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update with the MWE of the op:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@article{Giuliano:2009ib,
  author = {Giuliano, Paola and Ruiz-Arranz, Marta},
  title = {{Remittances, financial development, and growth}},
  journal = {Journal of Development Economics},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {90},
  number = {1},
  pages = {144--152},
  month = sep,
  publisher = {Elsevier B.V.},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005},
  uri = {\url{papers3://publication/doi/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2008.10.005}}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fontawesome}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\def\url#1{\href{#1}{\faExternalLink}}}

\begin{document} 
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{mwe}
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\end{document}
```