# Hyperlinked bibliography in LyX

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, lyx, natbib

There are at least two answers in standard LaTeX on how to add hyperlinks in the bibliography using the DOI or URL fields ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361414/link-button-instead-of-complete-url-in-bibliography) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314390/hyperlinked-bibliography)). However, I can't reproduce these results in LyX.

Ideally, I would like to reproduce the *American Economic Review* style, where a bullet on the left of the reference links to the DOI or URL field (see figure below). Ideally, I would also use the option `Natbib (BibTeX)` of LyX, as it is the one I am currently using. That being said, any solution to add hyperlinks in the references is welcome, e.g. one that makes the titles clickable.

[image]

Comment: it would be easier if you would switch to biblatex as suggested by one of your tags. biblatex has full hyperref integration. For natbib it depends on the bibtex style.

Comment: Ok why not but how can I do that then?

Comment: By reading the documentation https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: This is not helping. First, the documentation does not address my question. Second, it doesn't work for me to use Biblatex, because I run into a Biber error: unrecognized path "C:/..." while I am on linux and there is no path starting with "C:/..." in my LyX file. Not mentioning the fact that I don't know how to load my custom bib style with biblatex.

Comment: Sorry I don't use lyx and can't help you to set it up. I know that people are using biblatex there successfully.  You could ask the lux support if the documentation isn't working for you.