# How to exclude a specific bibtex field from being printed if doesn't contain specific text?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I had a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/how-to-sometimes-suppress-the-printing-of-the-url-field) but I was not able to adapt it to my case.

I want `biblatex` to print at the end of my bib entry the field `addendum` only in case the field indicates the original publication date `Original work published \dddd\` but not if the field indicates that the work is a reprint (or for that matter in any other case). Please consider the following MWE.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {The structural transformation of the public sphere: {An} inquiry into a category of bourgeois society},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Habermas, Jürgen},
    translator = {Burger, Thomas and Lawrence, Frederick},
    year = {1989},
    addendum = {Original work published 1962}
}
@incollection{test2,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    booktitle = {Deliberative democracy: {Essays} on reason and politics},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
    year = {1997},
    addendum = {Reprinted from {Hamlin} 1989 pp.17-34},
    pages = {67--91}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended for biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1}
\cite{test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

What I obtain is

[image: output]

but what I would like is to avoid printing the `addendum` in the first entry case, like this

[image: output]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `biblatex+biber` one can use source maps to nullify the content of bibtex fields

For the case in the question the following code does the trick (the regexp can be adjusted accordingly)

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=addendum, match=\regexp{[R|r]eprint.*},
            fieldset=addendum, null]
    }
  }
}
```